# Link to a date cell in QUERY criteria

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

I have the following formula and it works fine

```
=unique(query(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(
 {Database!A1:AB, (Database!N1:N)-(Database!M1:M)}, 
 "where Col9 <> '' AND Col1 >= date'2019-05-13'",1)), 999^99, 29) ,
 "Select Col1,Col9,Col29,Col13,Col14,Col21,Col22,Col23,Col24 label Col29 'Horas de Trabajo'",1))
```

And I have cell C55 that has same data 13 May 2019. But when I refer to this cell in my formula like this:

```
=unique(query(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(
 {Database!A1:AB, (Database!N1:N)-(Database!M1:M)}, 
 "where Col9 <> '' AND Col1 >='"&TEXT(C55,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'",1)), 999^99, 29) ,
 "Select Col1,Col9,Col29,Col13,Col14,Col21,Col22,Col23,Col24 label Col29 'Horas de Trabajo'",1))
```

I have an empty query (not an error, but empty).
Why?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: here is it - I created a separate spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19NOwpxDOMfRMMmJcZs_ht1brPnSEjbxAW4_1zf1Tptw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=UNIQUE(QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(
 {TEXT(Database!A1:A, "yyyy-MM-dd"), Database!B1:AB, (Database!N1:N)-(Database!M1:M)}, 
 "where Col9 <> '' 
    and Col1 >= '"&TEXT(A1, "yyyy-MM-dd")&"'", 1)), 999^99, 29),
 "select Col1,Col9,Col29,Col13,Col14,Col21,Col22,Col23,Col24 
  label Col29 'Horas de Trabajo'", 1))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I see my mistake now. Thanks a lot!